# Problem placing a button inside a MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to put a little button in my AnnotationViews to show some info about some places on a map. Sounds super basic? Well. I must be an idiot then...

I've looked at multiple examples, searched the whole internet, and I have ripped of 95% of my hair. It just doesn't work!

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)theAnnotation;
{
    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = nil;

    if([theAnnotation class] == [MyAnnotation class])
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:theAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;

    }
    return annotationView;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;
{
    NSLog(@"push %@", control);
}
```

Can some one please tell me why calloutAccessoryControlTapped never gets called? 
I get a nice and pretty annotation, but when I tap the blue button it just closes. I have tried adding a target to the button, nothing.

Please help me!

PS: I know I should reuse old annotation view and stuff, but i stripped all code that wasn't necessary to be sure that there wasn't something else that was screwing thins up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correctly set the `delegate` responding to the `MKMapViewDelegate Protocol`.

Also, make sure that all the views and superviews have `userInterActionEnabled` set to `YES`.

Comment: Yep, I've tried NSLogging the mapView.delegate and it's correct. Besides, viewForAnnotation is called upon same delegate so that wouldn't work either if that was the case. Thank you though :)

Comment: Did you check the `userInterActionEnabled` property of all views involved?

Comment: Tried adding it to the mapView, the annotation, the viewcontrollers view. No change.